# ViewLayer problem

Tags: viewlayers

I can't see the object in ViewLayer.
I had created a suit of armor and merged with the orginal design then I decided to create clothes to my character and did SHIFT D, it created the shirt for me but I can't see the object in ViewLayer, how can I do it?

In the image you can see that anxhe if I select a view layer object remains the same.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "ViewLayer"? The outliner at the top right on the screen? The mesh is most likely a child of the armature object and is listed below this entry. Just expand it.

Comment: Yes, the outliner at the top right. The problem is that I can't expand and I don't know why

Comment: The armature is hidden and can't be selected. Click on the "closed eye" icon right next to its name to make it visible. Then you can expand it and have a look at its children, the mesh parts. -- For easy access, you also can move all mesh objects in a separate collection. They will still be visible and accessible under the armature object but also in their own collection.